# Opacity Off on a:hover and a:visited

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

i'm Currently a 7th Grader studying CSS and HTML and it's only been my 6 months with it. i Love web-designing and it's something that I wanted to do. I am Also new here to the site and hoping that the community here would help me whenever I get stuck.

So here is my problem:
I don't know how to disable opacity when my mouse hovers on a link
Here is my petty CSS

```
 <style>

     body {

         background-size: cover;
         background-repeat: no-repeat
         }
     h2 {

         font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
         font-size: 60px;
         color: #FFDBFF;
         text-align: center;
         text-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #A093A0
     }
     h3 {

         font-family: 'playball', cursive;
         font-size: 57px;
         color: #FFCCCC;
         text-align: center;
         background-color: Black;
         opacity: 0.5
     }
     /* unvisited link */
     a:link {
         color: #FFCCCC;
         text-decoration: none;
     }
     /* visited link */
     a:visited {
         color: #BA9595;
     }
     /* mouse over link */
     a:hover {
         color: #FF00FF;
     }
     /* selected link */
     a:active {
         color: #0000FF;
     }
 </style>
```

Html:

### Some Random text with Logo/banner/title

```
         <h3> Home </h3>
     </a>
     <a href="">
         <h3> Link </h3>
     </a>
     <a href="">
         <h3> Link </h3>
         </a>
```

it's kind'uv'a hard for me figuring out how to do this so THANKS A LOT!! :)))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted whichever satisfies your needs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity is very simple to use in CSS. You can set the value of an object's opacity to any number from 0 to 1, with 1 being fully opaque and 0 being invisible.

Here is an example on how opacity could be used in CSS.

```
a {
    /*At a normal state, this link is halfway visible*/
    opacity: 0.5;
}

a:hover {
    /*When the mouse is hovering over this link, it is fully visible.*/
    opacity: 1;
}

a:active {
    /*While this link is being pressed, it is invisible.*/
    opacity: 0;
}
```

If you want to make sure that your link is fully visible when it is being hovered over by the mouse, you would do this:

```
a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #FF00FF;
}
```

---

## Update

After rereading your code, I now realize that because all of your are h3's nested inside of links, you will need to set the opacity of the h3 rather than the link itself.

For example, if you want your links to have a full opacity when hovered you would use this code:

```
a > h3 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And...

```
a > h3:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

What the ">" does is it only applies the style to the object that is a direct child of the parent object. In this case, "a > h3" means that this style will only apply to h3's that are directly nested inside of a link.

This way, only h3's that are nested inside of links will have their opacity changed.
For extra measure, I created a JSFiddle that gives an example of how that code would work. You can find that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/41n69vx7/).

Comment: I've just updated my response, hopefully the new information will help you.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!!
You helped me and educated me at the same time :))))
Could I apply ">" that to any tags? is there a "<"??

Comment: The ">" form of nesting will work with any two tags, as long as they properly put into the HTML. Here is a great link that can help you better understand how they work: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp   :)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Set the `opacity` on `hover` like this:

```css
a h3{
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #FF00FF;
}

a:hover h3{
  opacity: 1;  /* or set it to 0, whatever you want */
  color: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><h3>Link</h3></a>
```

Checkout this documentation on `opacity`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: this does not address the format used in the OP's mark-up, where the h3 is wrapped inside the anchor and its only the h3 that he wishes to style not the anchor, I would down vote but it costs me a point

Comment: @CodeUniquely Oops! Didnt notice the update in the question. Answer updated. Thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: @DinkleFarts What browser and OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are using opacity:0.5 in h3, if h3 is an anchor then on hover you simply would have to give opacity:1

It would also be helpful if you could post your html as well

Read this article as well, css tricks has a lot of good articles

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is like this:

```
<h3>This is a <a>link</a>.</h3>
```

It's originally not possible with CSS even if you have a `opacity: 1` in the `a:hover` css statement.

However, you may find some other methods to mimic this. One way is to keep the `a` tag out of the `h3` tag, and use relative/absolute positioning to move it over `h3`, like http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/.

Another(possibly easier) way is to keep away from the half-transparent `h3`. You may use transparent background color and manually set the inside texts transparent with classes.